# Avoid rollback of outer transaction when an inner transaction fails - Hibernate java

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, rollback

We have a inner transaction which fails due to data exception at db layer. This not only rollbacks the inner transaction but closes the complete method call. 
We do have catch blocks added and also @Transactional (dontRollbackOn=RuntimeException.class). But still the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without the code no-one can help you.

Comment: Please create and publish a working example.